# plot a graphic with two different time ranges

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to plot a violin graphic with a year data range and a point graphic with a month date range (so two plots in a same graphic, red dot is from a month data), but the results show "Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list'". Could someone help me out this?

```
p5 <- unique_client %>%
  filter(Date >= "2015-11-01" & Date <= "2016-09-30") %>%
  mutate(dd = format(Date, '%a'),
         mm = format(Date, '%m'),
         yy = format(Date, '%Y'),
         ww = format(Date, '%W')) %>%
  group_by(yy, mm, ww, dd) %>%
  arrange(mm) %>%
  filter(type %in% c("contact","prompt","panel")) %>%
  summarise(num_convs = sum(convs),
            recovered_sales = sum(sales),
            num_sends = sum(fired),
            num_approved = sum(opened),
            num_engaged = sum(clicked)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dd, y=recovered_sales)) +
  geom_violin(aes(x=dd, y=recovered_sales), fill= "#99cc00") +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=dd, y=recovered_sales), width=0.1, color= "#666666") +
  geom_point(subset(unique_client, YYMM %in% c("Sep-16"), aes(x= dd, y= recovered_sales)))
```

[image]

```
structure(list(data = structure(list(yy = c("2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016"), mm = c("11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09"), ww = c("43", "44", 
"44", "44", "44", "44", "44", "44", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", 
"45", "45", "46", "46", "46", "46", "46", "46", "46", "47", "47", 
"47", "47", "47", "51", "51", "51", "51", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"00", "00", "00", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", 
"13", "13", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "15", "15", 
"15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", "16", 
"16", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "21", "21", "21", "21", 
"21", "21", "21", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "24", "24", "24", "24", "24", 
"24", "24", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "26", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "27", "27", "27", "27", "27", "27", 
"27", "28", "28", "28", "28", "28", "28", "28", "29", "29", "29", 
"29", "29", "29", "29", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
"31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "33", "34", 
"34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "34", "35", "35", "35", "35", "35", 
"35", "35", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "36", "37", "37", 
"37", "37", "37", "37", "37", "38", "38", "38", "38", "38", "38", 
"38", "39", "39", "39", "39", "39"), dd = c("Sun", "Fri", "Mon", 
"Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Fri", 
"Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", 
"Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", 
"Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Mon", "Fri", "Sat", 
"Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", 
"Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Mon", "Thu", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", 
"Mon", "Sat", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Sun", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", 
"Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", 
"Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Mon", "Tue", 
"Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Mon", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", 
"Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", 
"Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", 
"Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", 
"Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", 
"Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Mon", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", 
"Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Fri", "Mon", "Sat", "Sun", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed", 
"Fri", "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"), num_convs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 3L), recovered_sales = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 17100, 22200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 21870, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11000, 0, 6500, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 8600, 0, 5300, 6500, 0, 14000, 5800, 24280, 0, 10800, 13205, 
4700, 9900, 6300, 0, 0, 14200, 14200, 4300, 6300, 0, 5300, 0, 
24500, 14200, 0, 6800, 5600, 14200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31500, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 24400, 43500, 9700, 0, 20300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19400, 
6300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11800, 0, 5100, 10500, 0, 0, 30500, 6000, 
29600, 0, 0, 19500, 0, 9000, 0, 0, 0, 11600, 38060, 0, 6800, 
31200, 17100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16000, 8000, 19800, 
0, 14000, 14000, 5000, 0, 9000, 12000, 21000, 32900, 0, 27000, 
7300, 0, 0, 12000, 0, 0, 14400, 0, 0, 6700, 0, 6000, 26300, 0, 
76000, 0, 8100, 10200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16800, 0, 33800, 25500, 0, 
0, 6300, 7300, 23600, 16000, 0, 0, 15000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14000, 
9500, 15000, 0, 15000, 31340, 18600, 0, 0, 15000, 15000, 15000, 
28200, 15000, 0, 5600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30000, 15000, 13200, 0, 36100, 
0, 0, 30000, 15000, 0, 0, 15000, 15000, 0, 0, 30000, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23800, 0, 0, 0, 29800, 0, 15000, 0, 7500, 0, 17300, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 28500, 0, 0, 5600, 7600, 12200, 6300, 0, 33000, 15600, 
0, 0, 9500, 9500, 0, 10500, 4800, 6100, 15600, 5400, 0, 17200, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 22680, 13600, 7000, 0, 0, 13800, 5100, 4800, 0, 0, 
0, 4700, 0, 24600, 4800, 31700, 13200, 39780, 0, 32520), num_sends = c(9L, 
10L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 19L, 11L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
0L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 12L, 6L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 15L, 
7L, 10L, 3L, 19L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 13L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 15L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 11L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 3L, 9L, 
11L, 14L, 7L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 
10L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 
10L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 2L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 
5L, 8L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
7L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 16L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 3L, 
17L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 
8L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 8L, 
15L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 
8L, 13L, 11L, 5L, 14L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 15L, 18L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 20L, 5L, 4L, 18L, 10L, 15L, 9L, 15L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 11L, 
8L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 8L, 10L, 13L), num_approved = c(4L, 
4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 14L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 1L, 
7L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 11L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L), num_engaged = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -305L), vars = list(
    yy, mm, ww), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("yy", "mm", "ww", "dd", 
"num_convs", "recovered_sales", "num_sends", "num_approved", 
"num_engaged")), layers = list(<environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
    x = dd, y = recovered_sales), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = structure(list(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = structure(list(
        family = NULL, face = "bold", colour = NULL, size = 8, 
        hjust = NULL, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
        margin = structure(c(2.9995, 0, 0, 0), class = c("margin", 
        "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), debug = NULL), .Names = c("family", 
    "face", "colour", "size", "hjust", "vjust", "angle", "lineheight", 
    "margin", "debug"), class = c("element_text", "element")), 
        axis.text.y = structure(list(family = NULL, face = "plain", 
            colour = NULL, size = 10, hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, 
            angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            2.9995, 0, 0), class = c("margin", "unit"), valid.unit = 8L, unit = "pt"), 
            debug = NULL), .Names = c("family", "face", "colour", 
        "size", "hjust", "vjust", "angle", "lineheight", "margin", 
        "debug"), class = c("element_text", "element")), axis.line = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), axis.title = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element"))), .Names = c("legend.position", "axis.text.x", 
    "axis.text.y", "axis.line", "axis.ticks", "axis.title"), class = c("theme", 
    "gg"), complete = FALSE, validate = FALSE), coordinates = <environment>, 
    facet = structure(list(shrink = TRUE), .Names = "shrink", class = c("null", 
    "facet")), plot_env = <environment>, labels = structure(list(
        x = "", y = "", title = "Best Sale Weekdays"), .Names = c("x", 
    "y", "title"))), .Names = c("data", "layers", "scales", "mapping", 
"theme", "coordinates", "facet", "plot_env", "labels"), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of `deput(p5)` into your question.

Comment: `dput()` is what he meant.

Comment: hi, i have pasted the dput(), hope this can help you to figure out.

Comment: I think what we need to see is a portion of your data (or something that matches its structure), and I am getting errors when I try to load either the full `p5` ggplot object or just the data portion. Further, I am not at all clear on what you want the plot result to look like. Could you show an example of a *correct* plot style (even if it is just editted in mspaint)?

Comment: Sorry for late to explain, I have attached a graph. Basically, I like to compare  monthly average (red dot) with a year box-plot. Under dplyr, subset() cannot work. is there any better way to improve this?